# php fread() vs jquery $.get

Tags: php, jquery, fread

For reading content from a different file, i can use php or jquery.

I was wondering: for outputting the result, which one is faster?

php method:

```
$readdir = fopen("content.php", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
echo '<div id="output">' . fread($readdir,filesize("content.php")) . '</div>';
fclose($readdir);
```

jquery method:

```
$("button").click(function(){
  $.get("content.php", function(data){
    $('#output').html(data);
  });
});
```

Comment: Will probably depend on the connection speeds / throughput / latency between each part. But likely the server will be quicker to retrieve the file, but then your have to get that data to the client, so if the client connection is slow then it may well take longer that getting it directly.

Comment: You could simply test both methods and find out

Comment: They are completely different: PHP runs on server, JQUERY runs on client. So, PHP is faster.

Comment: @AntonioPetricca so if the server is running on a dial-up connection, and the client on fibre (for example), the server will be faster ey?

Comment: As an aside `fopen("content.php", "r")` tries to open a local file, not external, so...

Comment: What on earth are you asking. So now you've changed it to "reading from a local file", but the js isn't reading from a local file. You can't compare the 2.

Comment: @Jon Stirling  that is not a fare comparison. And about the issue of external file: it just what your definition of "external" is. Fact is: it is not in the same file! So external is not a wrong word in this context

Comment: @mudraya That's the point.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the file serverside, the rendered html will be returned.
If you use $.get(), you will first get the html rendered page, and then request the data from the server. This restults in two requests, one for the page itself and one for the data, while the serverside rendering only requires one request. So the serverside rendering is faster in this case. Depending on your server, it can be a lot faster, or only some milliseconds.